# Any way to customize default nomask used in file_scan_directory() to allow Node.js modules?

Tags: 7, theming

I would like to use Node.js modules (such as `grunt-contrib-imagemin`) in my Drupal theme, but that adds `*.info` files which confuses Drupal.  If there were some way to change the default value of `nomask` used in `file_scan_directory()` to include 'node_modules' or some way to tell Node.js to use a local folder other than `node_modules` then the problem would be solved.

There is a post [here](http://www.wentsch.me/using-nodejs-modules-your-drupal-themes) that suggests patching Drupal core, but I'm hoping there's a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

As far as Drupal/PHP are concerned, no, there's no option other than either changing the default arguments to the function, or finding all calls to that function that don't include the 2nd arg, and updating things there. Either way you're likely to have to patch a core method or two.

NPM's convention is to use a folder called `node_modules`. They don't want to change that (https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2734, https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/775), but there *is* a [prefix](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders#node-modules) config option which may be suitable for your needs.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `prefix` option appears to only influence globally installed modules, and it's the locally installed modules that are causing the problem.